# Excel VBA Best Practice: One long macro or multiple small macros?

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for some suggestions on best practice for writing a macro. I am currently writing one that, when complete, will have about 200 IF/ELSE clauses. Each of these clauses will have about 10 IF/ELSE subclauses.

From an arrangement point of view, it will be very messy.

However, from a best practice point of view, would it be better to have:

- each of the clauses to call another macro, which will contain the subclauses?
- leave the subclauses within the overall body of the main macro?

Also, how would each of these options affect the speed of the macro (as in would option 1 be slower or faster than option 2)? The spreadsheet it is working on will have some 50k rows, and about 13 columns.

Edit 1:

This is a sample of the beginning of the code (very long and messy):

```
If Cells(j, 10) = "AT" Then

    ElseIf Cells(j, 10) = "BE" Then                           ' Belgian formatting
        If Cells(j, 9) <> "" Then
            If Left(Cells(j, 9), 2) = "B-" And IsNumeric(Right(Cells(j, 9), 1)) = True And Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 6 Then
                Cells(j, 8) = Cells(j, 9) & " " & Cells(j, 8)
                Cells(j, 9).ClearContents
                Cells(j, 8).Style = "input"
            ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(Cells(j, 9), 2)) = True And IsNumeric(Right(Cells(j, 9), 1)) = True Then
                Cells(j, 9) = "B-" & Cells(j, 9)
                Cells(j, 8) = Cells(j, 9) & " " & Cells(j, 8)
                Cells(j, 9).ClearContents
                Cells(j, 8).Style = "input"
            ElseIf IsNumeric(Right(Cells(j, 9), 2)) = True And Left(Cells(j, 9), 2) <> "B-" Then
                Cells(j, 9) = Trim(Right(Cells(j, 9), 6) & " " & Left(Cells(j, 9), Len(Cells(j, 9)) - 6))
                Cells(j, 9).Style = "Input"
            End If
        End If

    ElseIf Cells(j, 10) = "CH" Then                                             ' Swiss formatting
        If Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 4 Then
            Cells(j, 9) = "CH-" & Cells(j, 9)
            Selection.Style = "Input"
'            ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 7 And Left(Cells(j, 9), 2) = "CH" Then       Fix to include moving the post codes before the city name
'                Selection.Style = "Neutral"
        End If

    ElseIf Cells(j, 10) = "DE" Then                                             ' German formatting
        If Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) <> "D" Then
            Cells(j, 9) = "D-" & Cells(j, 9)
            Selection.Style = "Neutral"
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Right(Cells(j, 9), 5)) = True And Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 7 Then
            If Cells(j, 8) <> "" Then
                Cells(j, 8) = Cells(j, 9) & " " & Cells(j, 8)
                Cells(j, 9).ClearContents
                Cells(j, 8).Style = "Input"
            ElseIf Cells(j, 8) = "" Then
                Cells(j, 7) = Cells(j, 9) & " " & Cells(j, 7)
                Cells(j, 7).Style = "Input"
                Cells(j, 9).ClearContents
            End If
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Right(Cells(j, 9), 5)) And Len(Cells(j, 9)) > 8 Then
            If Mid(Cells(j, 9), Len(Cells(j, 9) - 7), 1) = "D" Then
                Cells(j, 9) = Trim(Right(Cells(j, 9), 7) & " " & Left(Cells(j, 9), Len(Cells(j, 9)) - 7))
                Cells(j, 9).Style = "Input"
            End If
        Else
            Cells(j, 9).Style = "Bad"
        End If

    ElseIf Cells(j, 10) = "IE" Then                                         ' Irish formatting
        If Cells(j, 9) <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(Right(Cells(j, 9), 1)) = True And (Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 9 Or Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 8) Then
            ElseIf (Len(Cells(j, 9)) <> 8 Or Len(Cells(j, 9)) <> 9) And Left(Cells(j, 9), 6) = "DUBLIN" Then
                If Mid(Cells(j, 9), Len(Cells(j, 9)) - 1, 1) = " " Then
                    Cells(j, 9) = Left(Cells(j, 9), 6) & " " & Right(Cells(j, 9), 1)
                    Cells(j, 9).Style = "Input"
                ElseIf Mid(Cells(j, 9), Len(Cells(j, 9)) - 2, 1) = " " Then
                    Cells(j, 9) = Left(Cells(j, 9), 6) & " " & Right(Cells(j, 9), 2)
                    Cells(j, 9).Style = "Input"
                End If
            ElseIf Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "A" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "B" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "E" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "F" _
                Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "H" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "I" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "J" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "N" _
                Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "O" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "P" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "Q" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "B" _
                Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "U" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "V" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "W" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "X" _
                Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "Y" Or Left(Cells(j, 9), 1) = "Z" Then
                Cells(j, 9).Style = "Bad"
            ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 9)) > 16 Then
                Cells(j, 9).Style = "Bad"
            ElseIf (Len(Cells(j, 9)) <> 8 Or Len(Cells(j, 9)) <> 9) And Left(Cells(j, 9), 6) <> "DUBLIN" Then
            End If
        End If
        If Cells(j, 8) = "DUBLIN" And Left(Cells(j, 9), 6) = "DUBLIN" Then
            Cells(j, 8).ClearContents
        ElseIf Cells(j, 7) = "DUBLIN" And Left(Cells(j, 9), 6) = "DUBLIN" Then
            Cells(j, 7).ClearContents
        ElseIf Cells(j, 8) = "CORK" And Left(Cells(j, 9), 4) = "CORK" Then
            Cells(j, 8).ClearContents
        End If

        ElseIf Cells(j, 10) = "US" Then                                         ' US formatting
        b = Len(Cells(j, 9))
        If Cells(j, 10) = "US" And b < 5 And b > 1 Then
            Cells(j, 9).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
            If b = 4 Then
                Cells(j, 9) = "0" & Cells(j, 9)
            Else
                Cells(j, 9) = "00" & Cells(j, 9)
            End If
        ElseIf Cells(j, 10) = "US" And Mid(Cells(j, 9), 3, 1) = " " And Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 7 Then
            Cells(j, 9) = Left(Cells(j, 9), 3) & "0" & Right(Cells(j, 9), 4)
        End If
        If Len(Cells(j, 8)) = 2 And Cells(j, 9) <> "" And Len(Cells(j, 9)) >= 5 Then
            Cells(j, 8) = Cells(j, 8) & " " & Cells(j, 9)
            Cells(j, 9).ClearContents
            Range(Cells(j, 8), Cells(j, 9)).Style = "Neutral"
        ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 8 Or Len(Cells(j, 9)) = 12 Then
            e = Application.Match(Left(Cells(j, 9), 2), Worksheets("Codes").Range("G:G"), 0)
            If Selection.Style <> "Neutral" And Not IsError(e) Then
                Selection.Style = "Input"
            End If
        ElseIf (Len(Cells(j, 9)) >= 5) And (Len(Cells(j, 8)) - 2) >= 0 Or (Len(Cells(j, 7)) - 2) >= 0 Then
            If Mid(Cells(j, 7), Len(Cells(j, 7)) - 2, 1) = " " And Cells(j, 8) = "" Then
                Cells(j, 9) = Right(Cells(j, 7), 2) & " " & Cells(j, 9)
                Cells(j, 7) = Trim(Left(Cells(j, 7), Len(Cells(j, 7)) - 2))
                Range(Cells(j, 7), Cells(j, 9)).Style = "Neutral"
            ElseIf Mid(Cells(j, 8), Len(Cells(j, 8)) - 2, 1) = " " And Len(Cells(j, 8)) - 2 >= 0 And IsNumeric(Right(Cells(j, 8), 1)) = False Then
                e = Application.Match(Right(Cells(j, 8), 2), Worksheets("Codes").Range("G:G"), 0)
                If Not IsError(e) Then
                    Cells(j, 9) = Right(Cells(j, 8), 2) & " " & Cells(j, 9)
                    Cells(j, 8) = Trim(Left(Cells(j, 8), Len(Cells(j, 8)) - 2))
                    Cells(j, 9).Style = "Input"
                    Cells(j, 8).Style = "Neutral"
                End If
            ElseIf Mid(Cells(j, 8), 3, 1) = " " And Len(Cells(j, 8)) - 2 >= 0 And IsNumeric(Right(Cells(j, 8), 3)) = True Then
                e = Application.Match(Left(Cells(j, 8), 2), Worksheets("Codes").Range("G:G"), 0)
                If Not IsError(e) Then
                    If Cells(j, 8).Style <> "Neutral" Or Cells(j, 8).Style <> "Input" Then
                        Cells(j, 8).Style = "Input"
                        Cells(j, 9).Style = "input"
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf Selection.Style <> "Neutral" Then
                Range(Cells(j, 8), Cells(j, 9)).Style = "Bad"
            End If
        Else
            If Selection.Style <> "Neutral" Then
                Selection.Style = "Bad"
            End If
        End If

    End If
```

Edit 2:

The data is in the format ADD1 (Cells(j,5), ADD2 (..6), ADD3 (...7), ADD4 (..8), ADD5 (...9, normally a post code which needs formatting), and ADD6 (..10, the ISO country code).

The point of the code is to check each line, and if the post code is in the correct format for the country (such as the US, Ireland, Austria, etc.) then it does nothing. However, if there is parts missing or in the incorrect order, it will go and either fix the fault (add in details, remove repeated data, move data around, or concatenate the data into a field), or highlight the data as being faulty.

As each country has different rules, and some countries have more than 1 rule, it gets very messy.

Comment: It depence on the Code and What you want to do. You could post your Code here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ they are very helpful. :)

Comment: just going for speed, doing all in one macro would be the fastest,,, however... if you cant read it, it wont help :)

Comment: @winner_joiner No! At Code Review we need actual code. To review. Questions without code are [very off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mast that's why I meant, post **the code**

Comment: depend much to how are your if, ex you need to check only a boolean result or your IF are complex?? can be that use some Select Case and with jump to goto:...., but  like other guys wrote, without code isn't possible to suggest you a good way.

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your code. However, you could create a function that expects an interface (using implements in a class). So you can possibly separate your code into classes which get passed into the function and will be called back. By doin this it removes your logic into more modularised classes which may be easier to manage. Will be slower than a macro switch statement or ifs. But more possibly more manageable. Depends on your code...

Comment: All, posted initial version of the code.

Comment: What does the data look like and what are the results you want?

Comment: @DirkReichel are you sure there is really a significant speed difference between one long macro and a properly modularized one? I don't think a simple `call`, `Sub` and `End Sub` will add measurable amount of execution time to any code.

Comment: @Fabrizio Man, suggesting jumps and GoTo? Is it 1975 again? GoTo is a spawn of satan, please don't write things like this on a programmer's help site! OP asked for help and best practices. GoTo is the worst possible "practice".

Comment: i never said it will be a huge impact... but going down to each bit which is need to be calculated, it is faster to do all in one macro... while i wouldn't do it this way ;)

Comment: @vacip you have my full support to your statement :)

Comment: As a general thought, [modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) is a good idea. So I say split it to well-named subs. It will be a lot easier to follow the general flow of the program, will be easier to manage and change parts of it. If you chose not to split your code, make sure to use proper indentation. You can use tools like [Rubber Duck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com/) to refactor your macro, and [Smart Indenter](https://www.add-ins.com/macro-products-for-Microsoft-Excel/how-to-indent-vba-code/how-to-indent-vba-code.htm) to auto-indent it.

Comment: however... to get a real "speed boost" put your ranges into a variable and read/change it there...

Comment: My guess is that your code will be too long by a factor of 200 or even 2000. When you have 200 clauses you are probably doing a lot of copying and pasting code with relatively little editing after each paste. If so, that which you paste is a function or sub which is waiting to be written (suitably abstracted of course).

Comment: `If Cells(j, 8) <> "" Then
                Cells(j, 8) = Cells(j, 9) & " " & Cells(j, 8)
                Cells(j, 9).ClearContents
                Cells(j, 8).Style = "Input"
            ElseIf Cells(j, 8) = "" Then
                Cells(j, 7) = Cells(j, 9) & " " & Cells(j, 7)
                Cells(j, 7).Style = "Input"
                Cells(j, 9).ClearContents
            End If` It could be wise to make use of If NOT Isempty(Cells(j,8)) in this case for the first if statement, and don't do elseif, but just else for the second part. This should speed things up as well.

Comment: If it's working then may be better suited to [Code Review [vba] ]9http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba?sort=newest).  For SO it's probably off-topic because, as the number and content of comments indicate, the answer is going to be opinion based.

Comment: I agree with vacip, better to split it up. You have obvious sub-procedures, one for each country. I work on the basis of trying to keep my procedures to being no longer than what I can see on the screen without scrolling. The calls will add an overhead, but should not be as significant as other factors, such as screen interaction.

Comment: @vacip hi, is not 1975, in that year I had three years, now someone more. And let me know how is a better way to exit from on loop to jump to a next step code ?!?! I'm open to any upgrade but I not think I'm old, certainly practical and fast, perhaps nostalgic memories Pascal ;-)

Comment: @Fabrizio I didn't mean to seem arrogant. Back in the day at my university they would fail you for so much as mentioning `GoTo` (except for the Assembly and other machine level courses). **Using goto** statement makes the logic of the program complex and tangled, creates "spaghetti code" that is hard to follow, understand and maintain. In the late 1960's, maybe 1970's they have shown that whatever you want to do can be done without `GoTo`. (Böhm-Jacopini theorem.) Dijkstra was also pushing this agenda, and it is more or less generally accepted today.

Comment: Now, exiting loops and other structures is a bit grey area. Theoretical programmers (I have seen them, they exist), mathematicians would say: _just do the freaking exit conditions properly, then you don't need breaks!_ And they would be right. But I admit, sometimes using a simple `Break` to get out of a loop is easier. Like using `Exit sub` looks better than putting one more `if` around your whole code. Still, it is "considered harmful", and whenever I do it, I feel a bit ashamed. [Example](https://xkcd.com/292/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just getting rid of a lot of repeating factors in your code would help a lot with readability.  For example use some range variables to remove all that repeating `Cells(j, xx)` - that will tidy up your code a lot and it's easier to maintain/refactor tidy code.

```
Dim rw As Range, c8, c9, c10
Set rw = Rows(j)

'use better variable names here...
Set c8 = rw.Cells(8)
Set c9 = rw.Cells(9)
Set c10 = rw.Cells(10)

If c10 = "AT" Then

ElseIf c10 = "BE" Then

    If c9 <> "" Then

        If Left(c9, 2) = "B-" And IsNumeric(Right(c9, 1)) And Len(c9) = 6 Then
            c8 = c9 & " " & c8
            c9.ClearContents
            c8.Style = "input"
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(c9, 2)) And IsNumeric(Right(c9, 1)) = True Then
            c9 = "B-" & c9
            c8 = c9 & " " & c8
            c9.ClearContents
            c8.Style = "input"
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Right(c9, 2)) And Left(c9, 2) <> "B-" Then
            c9 = Trim(Right(c9, 6) & " " & Left(c9, Len(c9) - 6))
            c9.Style = "Input"
        End If

    End If
```